# How to combine two update queries(MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two SQL Queries:
1. Get the the next row a row of where its status is "Active", Set it also to 'Active'
2. Remove the status of the previous row from the first sql query. Meaning, I want to remove the status of current row, move it to the next.

1. Code

```
UPDATE x AS a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id, count(*) FROM x WHERE id=(select min(id) FROM ref_school_year where id > (SELECT ID FROM x WHERE status='START'))
    ) AS b on a.id = b.id
SET a.status = 'START'
WHERE a.id > 0
```

2. Second sql query

```
UPDATE ref_school_year as a
INNER JOIN(
        SELECT * FROM ref_school_year
        WHERE status='START'
        ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
) as b on b.id = a.id
SET a.status=null
WHERE a.id > 0
```

Ex.

```
Before Query:
-----------------------------
| Rows     |     Status     |
-----------------------------
| 1        |    Active      |
| 2        |    null        |
```

```
After Queries:
-----------------------------
| Rows     |     Status     |
-----------------------------
| 1        |    null        |
| 2        |    Active      |
```

Comment: Sample data would help others understand your question better.

Comment: I'm not sure if first query will not work since you are sub-query of inner join consists of 2 "FROM"

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test (id int, status varchar(10));
insert test(id, status) values(1, 'Active'), (2, NULL);

update test t inner join (select id from test where status = 'Active' or exists (...)) t1 on t.id = t1.id set t.status = if(t.status = 'Active', NULL, 'Active');
```

The key for you is to use the IF function to update both at the same time. Hope I am right.

Comment: Hi! The Inner Join you provided returns all records, null and 'Active'. I wanted to only select and update Active row and the next row that should be null.